# Muss man bei Aufzählungen nach „beide“ und „allen“ ein Komma setzen?

Tags: punctuation, list

Sehr langweilige Frage: Was Kommasetzung vor Aufzählungen betrifft, ist irgendeine dieser Versionen<sup>1</sup> richtig?

> - Ich habe euch beiden(,) deinem Bruder und dir(,) gesagt, dass ihr die Katze nie mit … füttern sollt.

Das Gleiche für *alle(n)*:

> - Sie hat alle(,) Herrn Mustermann, den Dirigenten und mich(,)  überrascht.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Hier entstehen natürlich die Versionen dadurch, dass man die Kommata zwischen Klammern gleichzeitig dort lässt oder wegschmeißt.</sub>

Comment: Wenn zwischen "Dirigenten" und "und" noch ein Komma stünde, hätte der Satz wieder eine andere Bedeutung... Allerdings klänge "alle" dann etwas komisch.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In beiden Fällen sind die Kommas unbedingt notwendig. Allerdings lässt sich ein Fall konstruieren, in dem sie nicht nötig sind:

> Sie hat alle(,) Dirigenten und Musiker(,) überrascht.

Das geht dann deshalb auch ohne Komma, weil man dann eben alle Dirigenten und Musiker meint. Mit Komma hingegen bedeutet, dass der Einschub hier "alle" bzw. "beide" näher erläutert. Man könnte den Einschub dann auch mit Klammern statt Kommas abgrenzen, wodurch sehr deutlich wird, dass der Einschub eine Erläuterung ist.

Comment: Um einen Schritt weiterzugehen: Dein Beispiel zeigt sehr gut auf, warum es wichtig ist, derartige Einschübe durch Kommata abzugrenzen. Denn ohne ist die beabsichtigte Satzstruktur nur schwer erkennbar oder gar, wie in Deinem Beispiel, mehrdeutig.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft beziehungsweise eindeutig, aber eben nicht so wie geplant ;)

Comment: Achso! Das war eine Apposition.